# How to send email from Microsoft Teams Bot using Microsoft Graph Client as a different user?

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-exchange

I have LUIS embedded with my bot. If the LUIS cannot pick up or cannot understand the user's questions, I want the bot to send an email requesting for help from the concerned person.

This is what I have tried so far

```
const { ComponentDialog, WaterfallDialog, ConfirmPrompt } = require('botbuilder-dialogs');
const { ActivityTypes } = require("botbuilder");

const path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config({
   path: path.resolve('.env'),
});

const { ClientSecretCredential } = require("@azure/identity");

const { Client } = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client");

const { TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider } = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/authProviders/azureTokenCredentials");

let appInsights = require('applicationinsights');
appInsights.setup(process.env.APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY).start();

const CONFIRM_PROMPT = 'ConfirmPrompt';
const HELP_DIALOG = 'WaterfallDialog'

class HelpDialog extends ComponentDialog {

    constructor(id) {
        super(id);

        this.addDialog(
            new WaterfallDialog(HELP_DIALOG ,[
                this.getHelp.bind(this),
                this.sendEmail.bind(this)
            ]))
            .addDialog(new ConfirmPrompt(CONFIRM_PROMPT));

        this.initialDialogId = HELP_DIALOG;

    }

    async getHelp(stepContext) {
        await stepContext.context.sendActivity({ type: ActivityTypes.Typing });
        return await stepContext.prompt(CONFIRM_PROMPT, "I'm not sure what you are asking for, would you like me to get extra help?", ['Yes', 'No']);
    }

    async sendEmail(stepContext) {

        if(stepContext.result) {

            // Create TokenCredential
            const credential = new ClientSecretCredential(process.env.MicrosoftTenantID, process.env.MicrosoftAppId, process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword);

            // Set scope for TokenCredential
            const graphScope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default';
            const authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider(credential, { scopes: [graphScope] });

            // Create client for TokenCredential
            const graphClient = Client.initWithMiddleware({
                debugLogging: true,
                authProvider,
            });

            // Construct email object
            const mail = {
                subject: "Unknown Bot Questions",
                toRecipients: [
                {
                    emailAddress: {
                        address: "receiver@outlook.com",
                    },
                }],
                body: {
                    content: `<p>Hello,</p><p>I am having trouble querying the following questions to the Bot.</p><p>I need some assistance for the above queries.</p><p>Thanks</p>`,
                    contentType: "html",
                },
            };
            //Send Email
            await graphClient.api('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<ObjectId-Mailbox>/sendMail')
            .post(mail)
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
            })
            .catch((res) => {
                console.log(res);
            });

            return await stepContext.endDialog(stepContext.options);
        }
        else
        {
            return await stepContext.endDialog(stepContext.options);
        }
    }

}

module.exports.HelpDialog = HelpDialog;
```

I have authentication setup using `TeamsBotSsoPrompt` and `microsoft-graph-client` in another dialog and using the instance of `graphClient` in the dialog I want to send the email from.
But I want the email to be sent from a common email address rather than the receiver receiving email from multiple users.

Comment: This question isn't actually related to Teams itself, even though you're hitting it while building a Teams bot. It's basically a node/Exchange question - suggest you tag as such.

Comment: does your organization allow non-ssl connections?

Comment: YMMV, but I tend to use the microsoft-graph-client when it comes to sending out emails in my Teams bots. Very easy to work with.

Comment: @SteveJohnson That sounds great. Let me give microsoft-graph-client a try.

Comment: @SteveJohnson I have updated the question to use microsoft-graph-client. Now what different thing I need to do?

Comment: @AJ31, What error are you getting while trying with graph?

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT I am not getting any error. I want to send an email as email from Bot and not myself. Assuming I have the other credentials.

Answer (score 1):

To send an email from a common email address, you will need to first [create an application registration](https://help.cloudiway.com/article/how-to-create-azure-apps-registration/) in your Azure AD.

In the **API permissions** tab, select **Microsoft Graph**, then **Application permissions** and then add the **Mail.Send** permission.

Note down the client ID of your app reg and then create a client secret by clicking **Certificates and secrets**, create a secret and then note that down.

I'm not sure how're your storing and retrieving client ID, secrets, keys etc. but in my environment I'm using the env file and I've also installed the **@azure/identity** package as well, so mine looks a bit like this.

```
 const path = require('path');
   require('dotenv').config({
   path: path.resolve('.env'),
 });

 const {
   ClientSecretCredential
 } = require("@azure/identity");

 const {
   Client
 } = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client");

 const {
   TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider
 } = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph- 
   client/authProviders/azureTokenCredentials");

 // Create TokenCredential
 const credential = new 
   ClientSecretCredential(process.env.MicrosoftTenantID, process.env.MicrosoftAppId, process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword);

 // Set scope for TokenCredential
 const graphScope = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default';
 const authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider(credential, 
   {
    scopes: [graphScope]
    });

 // Create client for TokenCredential
 const graphClient = Client.initWithMiddleware({
    debugLogging: true,
    authProvider,
 });
```

With that in place, I retrieved the object ID of the user/mailbox I want to send the email from and make the graph call to send the email.

```
await graphClient.api('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/4ae760e0-8040-4cf1-a630-941c1240f7b0/sendMail')
.post(mail)
.then((res) => {
   console.log(res);
                    })
.catch((res) => {
   console.log(res);
});
```

I imagine there are a multitude of better ways of achieving this, but this works for me.

Comment: I am getting a `MODULE_NOT_FOUND` Error for the following line
`const {
    TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider
} = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/authProviders/azureTokenCredentials");`

Comment: I have tried moving around `node_modules` and look for the lib but couldn't find it

Comment: What version of the microsoft-graph-client do you have in the package.json?

Comment: The version is **2.2.1**. I tried updating the version but it's not updating.

Comment: Does it not let you update using npm i @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client@3.0.0

Comment: Actually it got stuck due to some reason. I had to restart and it eventually got updated.I am yet to get the Object ID of the mailbox I want to send emails from. Once I get that will  let you know if the whole thing works. Very much thanks for the help though!

Comment: So it's now giving me a `401 Error`. I have added the `Mail.Send` Permission to the app registration. Not sure what is the issue now.

Comment: 401 is a credentials issue. Did you add the Mail.Send as a delegated or application permission. Also, have you granted consent to the permissions as well?

Comment: Mail.Send is added as delegated permission.The permission consent has been granted.

Comment: Is your Graph call retrieving an access token successfully?

Comment: Yes Access Token is being retrieved correctly.

Comment: Can you post the latest code you have at all please?

Comment: I have updated the code I have so far. Also, how exactly do I check that I am receiving the Access Token correctly?

Comment: Are you able to make a successful call to Graph using the /me endpoint and have it post a response back to the console.log?

Another thing I thought of, does the Object ID you are sending the mail on behalf of, does it have an Exchange Online license?

Comment: Yes, to both of your questions

Comment: So it sounds like it’s making a successful call, is the permission Mail.Send set up as Delegated or as an Application?

Comment: I have mentioned this before. It's setup as Delegated Permission

Comment: My apologies, you did. Have you tried adding Mail.Send as an Application one instead? I've checked one of my bots and mine is set to Application.

Comment: Oh. I cannot set it as Application permission as I don’t have Admin access.I’ll see if I can get that else we’ve hit a roadblock here.Thank you for all your help though.It helped me a lot.